# Display a different background image by day of the week and time of day

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using the following javascript to display a different image depending on the time of day:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getHours();
if (n > 19 || n < 6)
  // If time is after 7PM or before 6AM, apply night theme to ‘body’
  document.body.className = "night";
else if (n > 16 && n < 19)
  // If time is between 4PM – 7PM sunset theme to ‘body’
   document.body.className = "sunset";
else
   // Else use ‘day’ theme
  document.body.className = "day";
});
```

http://codepen.io/jamesbarnett/pen/kdDBL

However I need to define the background image by a day of the week as well.

So for example on Monday, times between 6am - 12pm show an opening times image and 12pm -6am show a closing time image. Then Tuesday 6am - 4pm show an opening image and 4pm-8am show a closing image. Each day has different opening and closing times. So each day of the week need to be defined in the javascript for this to work.

Can anyone help me out?

I've played around using the following javascript and defined each image and time under each day, but cannot seem to get it working:

```
var days = [
'SUN', //Sunday starts at 0
'MON',
'TUE',
'WED',
'THU',
'FRI',
'SAT'
];
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: [*Date.prototype.getDay*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.16) will return 0 for Sunday through to 6 for Saturday, so `days[d.getDay()]` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what the code should look like for Sunday and Monday.  Class names are based on what you previously had plus the code for the day 0-6 (Sun-Sat).  You can declare an array for easier naming if you like, but you don't necessarily need to.

For Sunday after 8pm, the branch taken would use class=night0, Monday after 6am-12pm is class=day1...

Note:  for times after Monday 11:59pm, you need to specify Tuesday n >= 0 to some end time.
Note2:  I fixed some of your bugs for you as well.  When declaring time ranges, you should use and (&&) ie.  n>0 && n<12 would denote midnight up to 1159am, n>=12 && n<24 would denote Noon to 1159pm.

Using or (||) could introduce bugs.  For example, if you have n>0 || n<12, then n>0 will always be true after 12:00am and other branches will be skipped.

Demo:  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/uHgDF

JS:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getHours();
  var day = d.getDay();

  // change this to test days
   day =0;
  // n =0;

  if (day == 0 ) {
      if (n > 6 && n < 19) {
        // sun 6am - sun 6:59pm
        document.body.className = "day"+day; // night0 for sunday
      }
      else if (n >= 20 && n < 24) {
        // sun 800 - sun 1159pm
        document.body.className = "night"+day;
      }
      else {
        // Else use ‘day’ theme
        document.body.className = "sunset"+day;
      }
  }
  else if ( day == 1 ) {
    // today is monday
      if (n > 6 && n < 12) {
        // Mon 6:00am - Mon 11:59am
        document.body.className = "day"+day; // night1
      }
      else if (n >= 12 && n < 24) {
        // Mon 12pm - 1159pm
        document.body.className = "night"+day;
      }
      else {
        document.body.className = "sunset"+day;
      }
  }  
  else if ( day == 2 ) {
  // etc...
  }
});
```

CSS:

```
/* backgrounds */
.day0 { background:red; }
.sunset0 { background:green; }
.night0 { background:blue; }

/* backgrounds */
.day1 { background:yellow; }
.sunset1 { background:gray; }
.night1 { background:brown; }
```

Comment: Hi Will. Thank you ever so much. This looks perfect. I'm playing with it now. I will let you know how it goes :)

Comment: Hi Will. Just to let you know it works perfectly thank you so much. I have one other thing I need a little bit of help with if you would be willing to help me out. I've posted a question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26175530/modify-height-of-fold-unfold-effect I hope you're able to help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it like this:

```js
(function day(){

//get the hours

  var a = new Date();
  var n = a.getHours();
  if (n > 19 || n < 6){
    var s = "night";
  }
  else if (n > 16 && n < 19){
  
    var s = "sunset";
  }
  else{
    var s = "day";
  }

//get the day

var d = new Date();
var c = d.getDay();
  
var weekday=new Array(7);
weekday[0]="Monday";
weekday[1]="Tuesday";
weekday[2]="Wednesday";
weekday[3]="Thursday";
weekday[4]="Friday";
weekday[5]="Saturday";
weekday[6]="Sunday";
  
alert("Today is "+weekday[c]+" at "+s);
  
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create a more flexible structure to keep all the different combinations of openings and closings by day. In this case, as you say that *each day of the week need to be defined in the javascript for this to work*, I suggest having an array indexed by the day (0 for Sunday, 1 for Monday, 2 for Tuesday, and so on). In each day then you can keep all the backgrounds associated to the corresponding opening and closing hour.

```
  var background = function (d) {
    // All days must be defined in the backgrounds array.
    // You can have as many different opening/closing defined as you need.
    // In case of overlap return the first opening/closing that meets the condition.
    var backgrounds = [
      // Sunday
      [{opening: 0, closing: 5, background: 'night'},
       {opening: 19, closing: 23, background: 'night'}],
      // Monday
      [{opening: 0, closing: 5, background: 'night'},
       {opening: 19, closing: 23, background: 'night'}],
      // Tuesday
      [{opening: 0, closing: 5, background: 'night'},
       {opening: 17, closing: 18, background: 'sunset'},
       {opening: 19, closing: 23, background: 'night'}],
      // Wednesday
      [{opening: 0, closing: 5, background: 'night'},
       {opening: 19, closing: 23, background: 'night'}],
      // Thursday
      [{opening: 0, closing: 5, background: 'night'},
       {opening: 19, closing: 23, background: 'night'}],
      // Friday
      [{opening: 0, closing: 5, background: 'night'},
       {opening: 19, closing: 23, background: 'night'}],
      // Saturday
      [{opening: 0, closing: 5, background: 'night'},
       {opening: 19, closing: 23, background: 'night'}],
    ];
    var day = backgrounds[d.getDay()];
    var hour = d.getHours();

    for (var i = 0; i < day.length; i++) {
      if (day[i].opening <= hour && hour <= day[i].closing) {
        return day[i].background;
      }
    }
    // return day by default.
    return 'day';
  };
  $(document).ready(function(){
    document.body.className = background(new Date());
  }
```