# Modify height of fold/unfold effect

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using the following CodePen for a fold/unfold effect [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Esaqg):

I'm having a issue with the fold height. Ideally I need each fold to have a different height, however in the folded state you will see a large white space between each fold, which should not be there and something I am having a problem fixing.

I appreciate it may be better to use javascript to control the height, however again I have tried and failed. Is there anyone out there that can help me fix this code and make it workable.

Here is the current html and css:

```
<div id="folder">
  <input type="checkbox" id="toggle"/> <label for="toggle" id="toggle-label">fold/unfold</label>

   <div class="fold">
   This is a list of the fold<br>
       One<br>
       Two<br>
       Three<br>
       Four<br>
       Five<br>
       Six<br>
       Seven<br>
       Eight
    </div>
      <div class="fold"> Element 2 </div>
      <div class="fold"> Element 3 </div>
      <div class="fold"> Element 4 </div>
      <div class="fold"> Element 5 </div>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
body { 
    padding: 50px; 
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
};

#folder {
    width: 60%;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.fold {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #e5e5e5, #ccc);
    background: -moz-linera-gradient(top, #e5e5e5, #ccc);
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    color: #999;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    transition: all 0.3s linear;
};

#toggle {
    display: none;
}

#toggle-label {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #999;
    background: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
};

#toggle:not(:checked) ~ .fold:nth-child(odd) {
    margin-top: -82px;
    -webkit-transform: perspective(800px) rotateX(-80deg); 
    -moz-transform: perspective(800px) rotateX(-80deg); 
    transform: perspective(800px) rotateX(-80deg);
};

#toggle:not(:checked) ~ .fold:nth-child(even) {
    margin-top: -84px;
    -webkit-transform: perspective(800px) rotateX(80deg); 
    -moz-transform: perspective(800px) rotateX(80deg); 
    transform: perspective(800px) rotateX(80deg);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to reduce the height of the folded items after the fold was done:

Relevant selectors are this two - adjust the height to the value you want to have - I used 100px:

```
#toggle:not(:checked) ~ .fold:nth-child(odd) {
  margin-top: -82px;
  height:100px; /* added height when folded */
    -webkit-transform: perspective(800px) rotateX(-80deg); 
    -moz-transform: perspective(800px) rotateX(-80deg); 
    transform: perspective(800px) rotateX(-80deg);
}

#toggle:not(:checked) ~ .fold:nth-child(even) {
    margin-top: -84px;
  height:100px;  /* added height when folded */
    -webkit-transform: perspective(800px) rotateX(80deg); 
    -moz-transform: perspective(800px) rotateX(80deg); 
    transform: perspective(800px) rotateX(80deg);
}
```

Check the snippet below

```css
body { 
 padding: 50px; 
 font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

#folder {
 width: 60%;
 padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.fold {
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #e5e5e5, #ccc);
 background: -moz-linera-gradient(top, #e5e5e5, #ccc);
 padding: 10px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 300px;
 color: #999;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
 transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

#toggle { display: none; }

#toggle-label {
 display: inline-block;
 cursor: pointer;
 margin-bottom: 50px;
 border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
 font-size: 11px;
 color: #999;
 background: #fff;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 border-radius: 5px;
 padding: 5px;
}

#toggle:not(:checked) ~ .fold:nth-child(odd) {
  margin-top: -82px;
  height:100px;
    -webkit-transform: perspective(800px) rotateX(-80deg); 
 -moz-transform: perspective(800px) rotateX(-80deg); 
 transform: perspective(800px) rotateX(-80deg);
}

#toggle:not(:checked) ~ .fold:nth-child(even) {
 margin-top: -84px;
  height:100px;
    -webkit-transform: perspective(800px) rotateX(80deg); 
 -moz-transform: perspective(800px) rotateX(80deg); 
 transform: perspective(800px) rotateX(80deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="folder">
  <input type="checkbox" id="toggle"/> <label for="toggle" id="toggle-label">fold/unfold</label>
      
  <div class="fold">
    This is a list of the fold<br>
    One<br>
    Two<br>
    Three<br>
    Four<br>
    Five<br>
    Six<br>
    Seven<br>
    Eight
   </div>
   <div class="fold">
    Element 2
   </div>
   <div class="fold">
    Element 3
   </div>
   <div class="fold">
    Element 4
   </div>
   <div class="fold">
    Element 5
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi easeee. Thank you for the help. However i've still got one issue. If I want each fold to be different heights how could I do this? As for example I want fold 1 to be 300px and fold 2 to be 500px, but this also breaks the fold effect. Is there anyway to make each fold automatically fit the content.

Comment: @JamesWdev yes, but you will need javascript to calculate the height of each separate div and than animate it based on that. You will also have to set the negative top margins dynamically.

Comment: I've worked on the Javascript and I've got it. Thanks easwee.

Comment: @JamesWdev glad to hear you sorted it out. Way to go!